# How to rename array keys being ordered by preg_match_all?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to rename some array keys I've put into an array that have been matched by preg_match_all to organize the data.

I have the following:

```
$array = [
    '1. first paragraph goes here',
    '<img src="http://www.xxs.com/image2asdasd.jpg">',
    '2. second paragraph is also here',
    '3. third paragraph is much longer then the rest',
    '<img src="http://www.xxs.com/image2asdasd.jpg">'
];

foreach($array as $string){
    if(preg_match_all("/(?:\d)\. (.*)/", $string, $output_array)) {
        foreach($output_array[0] as $instructions_output){
            $info[] = $instructions_output;
        }
    }
    if(preg_match_all("/<*img[^>]*src *= *[\"\']?([^\"\']*)/", $string, $cought_array)) {
        $info[] = $cought_array[1][0];
    }
}
```

If I `print_r($info)` I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1. first paragraph goes here
    [1] => http://www.xxs.com/image2asdasd.jpg
    [2] => 2. second paragraph is also here
    [3] => 3. third paragraph is much longer then the rest
    [4] => http://www.xxs.com/image2asdasd.jpg
)
```

Since they're being ordered by preg_match, **I want to do the following**:

```
Array
(
    [text] => 1. first paragraph goes here
    [image] => http://www.xxs.com/image2asdasd.jpg
    [text] => 2. second paragraph is also here
    [text] => 3. third paragraph is much longer then the rest
    [image] => http://www.xxs.com/image2asdasd.jpg
)
```

**What I tried:**

I tried renaming it inside where I set it to `$info['text'][]` and `$info['image'][]` but that only divides them like I'm showing below.

```
Array
(
    [text] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1. first paragraph goes here
            [1] => 2. second paragraph is also here
            [2] => 3. third paragraph is much longer then the rest
        )

    [image] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.xxs.com/image2asdasd.jpg
            [1] => http://www.xxs.com/image2asdasd.jpg
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Array
(
    [text] => 1. first paragraph goes here
    [image] => http://www.xxs.com/image2asdasd.jpg
    [text] => 2. second paragraph is also here
    [text] => 3. third paragraph is much longer then the rest
    [image] => http://www.xxs.com/image2asdasd.jpg
)
```

this is not a array. if there are 3 text and 2 image index, how to access it?

Comment: Yeah, I had forgotten that the key names can't be the same.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the index of an array element with a string key, first, get the original value of the array element that you want to replace to a string key. Then, delete the array element. Finally, add a new element to the array with the key. **Note: In PHP, you can't have two or more elements with the same key.**
Example:

```
<?php

$value_backup = $array[0];
unset($array[0]);
$array['text'] = $value_backup;

?>
```

Comment: Oh right, I forgot that we can't have two keys with the same names. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad I helped! If my answer helped you, please set my answer as the correct answer